# For loop with array elements Inside function. How to return the function output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How can i get the output of these below two for loop's console.log via function call. Code snippet given below.

**CODE BELOW:**

```js
var scoreDolphins = [96, 108, 89];
var scoreKolas = [88, 91, 110];

var avgD_Div = scoreDolphins.length;
console.log(avgD_Div);

var avgK_Div = scoreKolas.length;
console.log(avgK_Div);

var calcAvgF = function() {

    for (let scoreItem_D = 0; scoreItem_D < scoreDolphins.length; scoreItem_D++) {

        console.log(scoreDolphins[scoreItem_D]);
             
    }
    console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (let socreItem_K = 0; socreItem_K < scoreKolas.length; socreItem_K++) {

        console.log(scoreKolas[socreItem_K]);

    }

    return calcAvgF;

}

console.log(calcAvgF);
```

Comment: What's the expected result? And why do you log the function itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calcAvgF` should not return `calcAvgF` iteslf. Also you should call `calcAvgF` function unstead of `console.log(calcAvgF)`

```js
var scoreDolphins = [96, 108, 89];
var scoreKolas = [88, 91, 110];
var avgD_Div = scoreDolphins.length;

var avgK_Div = scoreKolas.length;
var calcAvgF = function () {
  for (let scoreItem_D = 0; scoreItem_D < scoreDolphins.length; scoreItem_D++) {
    console.log(scoreDolphins[scoreItem_D]);
  }
  for (let socreItem_K = 0; socreItem_K < scoreKolas.length; socreItem_K++) {
    console.log(scoreKolas[socreItem_K]);
  }
}
calcAvgF();
```

Comment: Thanks, But why do i also get undefined on the output of the above code?

Comment: Please check now. There is no undefined in the log